# Why do these two situations allow a noun to be singular and plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, measure-phrases

Examples:
"Two miles is too far to walk" vs "There are two miles"
In the first situation, the noun is seen as singular, while the noun is seen as plural in the second situation. What is the reason that allows this noun to be both plural and singular.

Comment: I can't imagine saying "There are two miles." Where did you read that?

Comment: @livresque No no no, that's the wrong duplicate. It's about measure phrases counting as singulars: "Five cups of sugar is all you'll need for this recipe."

Comment: @tchrist Bingo, thank you. I'm all thumbs.  A couple of thumbs is all you need.  Two thumbs is enough.